# How to remove text before link

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to remove everything before a link in some text. I'm using Notepad++ and have tried several regular expressions but nothing works correctly.

What I want:

Before

```
92812/abc.png', 'https://www.bla1bla1.com
```

After

```
https://www.bla1bla1.com
```

thx

Answer (score 3):

In regular expression mode, search for:

```
^.*?(http)
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

This will strip out everything in the line preceding the first appearance of `http`.

If you have irregular text that contains `http` but is not a URL, you may may want to use a more restrictive regex pattern, such as:

```
^.*?\b(http)
```

Or more restrictive still:

```
^.*?\b(https?://)
```